# Using DBeaver, when attempting to export data from CSV to my Hive database, the export freezes?

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, dbeaver

I have four CSV files that I've been trying to import into four different hive tables. I've imported the CSV files into a a flat file databases and the ddl has been constructed correctly. When trying to import the CSV files into the hive tables, the task freezes right before it "commits." If I set the commit interval at 10,000 records, it will freeze at 9900. If set at 100000, it freezes at 99800. Any idea why this is happening? I've been stuck trying to figure out what is wrong for the last day and a half. I'm using DBeaver as my data admin tool.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have raw HDFS access? If so, why are you using a tool to insert into Hive?

Comment: I do apparently, but I wanted to see if it could be done with DBeaver. I'm an intern, so I'm just starting to get a feel for the backend our company uses. I did end up doing it via command line though and it worked after ssh-ing into the right environment. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being the Hive database itself. I switched over to one of our alternative Hive environments and it worked fine.